# Get JSON Object length with defined type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have seen questions and answers pertaining to finding the length of a JSON object for the purpose of just knowing. However, I need to check it later with an IF statement, and I'm getting an `undefined` type for the length.

When I do this:

```
$(function() {
      $('#filter_search').click(function() {               
          var data = JSON.stringify($('#filterform').serializeObject());
          var fetch = true;
          if ((JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower'].indexOf("foo") == -1 && JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower'].indexOf("bar") == -1) || (Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)).length == 1))  {
              alert("Please input at least one option");
              fetch = false;
          }
      ...
```

I never catch that if statement, even when I know the length is 1. The type of that length is also `undefined`. How can I get a meaningful (meaning that I can use in this if statement) return of length for a JSON object?

My JSON object is always of length 1 or of length 2. It will either look like this:

```
{"checkboxes":"foo","checkboxes-lower":["bar", "tar"]}
```

Or it will look like this:

```
{"checkboxes":["foo", "bar"]}
```

The above is what is outputted when I run this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($('#filterform').serializeObject()));
```

Where serializeObject is:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name]) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
  };
```

Essentially what I am asking is:

How do I return anything besides an `undefined` variable when doing `Object.keys(data)`? It can be a string, int, whatever. As long as I can check for equality in the if statement.

**EDIT**

```
console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)).length);
```

Outputs the same thing. Either 1 or 2, but doesn't give me a type

Comment: Could you provide a simple HTML source that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Could explain your problem a bit clearly? With examples may be? If it helps: `Object.keys({"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c"}).length === 3`

Comment: Also, why are you stringifying the object, and then parsing it back to get the length? Can you not save a reference to the object, after serialising the form, and use that in `Object.keys()` instead?

Comment: @Thrustmaster, doesn't matter. Either way I try to grab keys, I get `undefined` as my type and I can't use it in the if statement. But, you are correct. I just stringified it to get a look at what was happening with alert

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)))` and update the question with the output?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jNFY7/ You get the message if you have checkboxes from exactly one `name`d set checked, as specified in the code. Are you sure you didn't mean to test if `length < 1`?

Comment: It works for me with your code, are you able to try it in isolation?  And have you tried `if (Object.keys({"checkboxes":["foo","bar"]}).length == 1) { alert("Please input at least one option"); }` to see if you see the alert?  (I do.)

Comment: So, I just updated my if statement, I didn't think I needed the entire thing, but maybe I did

Comment: I switched around the logic elements in the if statement and it worked. It sorta makes sense because when the length of the JSON object is 1, there is no 'checkboxes-lower' so I couldn't do indexOf. You guys led me to the answer by asking good questions, so I'd like to accept someone's answer here, I just don't know how to make that work haha. Is this some javascript thing I wasn't aware of?

Comment: JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower'] is undefined in your length 1 example ({"checkboxes":["foo", "bar"]}), which will short-circuit your if.

Comment: I see, that's completely correct. And if I just have that bit of logic first, then it triggers the if and goes directly into the meat of the if statement

Comment: You can just do `((JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower']||[]).indexOf("foo") == -1 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `'checkboxes-lower'` property in your object then `JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower']` is `undefined` and `(JSON.parse(data)['checkboxes-lower']).indexOf` is trying to do `(undefined).indexOf` which will give an error that stops execution of your code at that point before it can evaluate the `.length` of the array returned by `Object.keys()`.

Test the length first, and test whether that property exists before trying to use it. Also, it's very messy to keep calling `JSON.parse()` everywhere. Why not keep a reference to the object:

```
      var data = $('#filterform').serializeObject(),
          json = JSON.stringify(data),
          fetch = true;
      if (Object.keys(data).length == 1 ||
               !data['checkboxes-lower'] ||     // test that property exists before using
               data['checkboxes-lower'].indexOf("foo") == -1 && // .indexOf on it
               data['checkboxes-lower'].indexOf("bar") == -1)  {
          alert("Please input at least one option");
          fetch = false;
      }
```

(Also I don't think you need to use `.indexOf()` to separately test for `"foo"` and `"bar"`, because from your description it sounds like if the `'checkboxes-lower'` property exists at all it will always be an array with at least one of those two options. So the `!data['checkboxes-lower']` test might be enough?)

By the way, [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You either have an object (`data`, in the code I show), or you have JSON which is the string representation returned by `JSON.stringify()`, which I've put in a new variable called `json`.